# How do I overlay `.mbtiles` tiles on my Google Maps Object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, mbtiles

I have a Linode server where I'd like to upload `custom-tiles-that-cover-USA-only.mbtiles`. I also have `script.js` on the server, which has this basic code for loading a Google Maps object and putting it on the page.

```
    var mapWrapperElem= document.getElementById("mapWrapper");
    map=                new google.maps.Map(mapWrapperElem, /* {Object with  GMaps options}*/);
```

When a user navigates their browser to my server, I'd like the `.mbtiles` tiles to load on top of my GMaps object. Maybe using the [ImageMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay) function? How do I get `.mbtiles` tiles on top of a GMaps object?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library to load vector tiles in Google Maps:
https://github.com/techjb/Vector-Tiles-Google-Maps